# how to define global variable python?

Tags: python

How do i use a global var in python?

```
class CompareRectangles(object):

    debugging = True

    def globals():
        global debugging
        debugging = True

    def __init__(self,r1,r2):
        # globals()
        self.r1 = r1
        self.r2 = r2
        self.initialise_boundary_tests()

    def method(self):
        if debugging:
            print("hello debugger")
```

`compare_rects = CompareRectangles(r1,r2)
NameError: global name 'debugging' is not defined`

Comment: What are you trying to do? This is clearly an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a global, that's a class variable. You can access it by `self.debugging`. I don't understand why you need the `globals()` method.

```
class CompareRectangles(object):

    debugging = True

    def __init__(self,r1,r2):
        self.r1 = r1
        self.r2 = r2
        self.initialise_boundary_tests()

    def method(self):
        if self.debugging:
            print("hello debugger")
```

Comment: i guess i dont. i got confused whilst learning multiple languages at once. thanks.

Comment: global has different meanings in diff languages and generic meaning too.

Comment: Fair enough; but it's not a Python global :).

Answer (score 0):

Really close. You need to add `self`

Change

```
def method(self):
    if debugging:
        print 'hello debugger'
```

to

```
def method(self):
    if self.debugging:    <-- notice the self
        print 'hello debugger'
```

[Code](https://ideone.com/QTxhVk) to explain your example :)

Comment: You need to add some quotes to your strings. And it looks like the OP is using the `print()` function, not the `print` statement.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks. I actually did put quotes in the ideone link but forgot to put here. :)

Comment: the addition of the class var information made the other answer more informative, but thanks.